# Updating specific single or several MySQL rows with duplicate HTML attribute names

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to update 1 or several MySQL rows in PHP while the HTML input and select tag names have the same attribute name.

The form is displayed in an HTML modal.

I've tried setting the HTML tag names as an array while passing a hidden primary key to identify each row and therefore update that specific row.

As well as a foreach and for loops to loop through the array results but no luck, the MySQL rows don't get updated.

modal.php file:

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Recipe name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipe_name" value="<?php echo $row['recipe_name']; ?>" />
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Crop</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recipe_crop" value="<?php echo $row['recipe_crop']; ?>" />
                </div> 

<?php 
                $query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE recipe_name = '" . $row['recipe_name'] . "' AND recipe_crop = '" . $row['recipe_crop'] . "';");
                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){            
              ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="recipe_id[]" value="<?php $row2['recipe_id']; ?>" readonly>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Hardware</label>
                  <select name="hardware[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="<?php echo $row2['recipe_hardware']; ?>">CURRENTLY: <?php echo $row2['recipe_hardware']; ?></option>
                    <option value="LIGHTS">LIGHTS</option>
                    <option value="WATER_PUMP">WATER PUMP</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Action</label>
                  <select name="action[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="<?php echo $row2['recipe_action']; ?>">CURRENTLY: <?php echo $row2['recipe_action']; ?></option>
                    <option value="ON">ON</option>
                    <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

PHP update code:

```
$rid = $_POST['recipe_id'];
$recipe_hardware = $_POST['hardware'];
$recipe_action = $_POST['action'];
foreach ($rid as $key => $id) {
                $sql = "UPDATE recipes SET recipe_hardware = '" . $recipe_hardware[$key] . "', recipe_action = '" . $recipe_action[$key] . "' WHERE recipe_id = '" . $id . "';";
                $query1 = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
                if ($query1) {

                    $this->messages[] = "Recipe edited successfully.";

                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Recipe not updated.";
                }
            }
```

The expected result is to be able to update the specified rows only.

Comment: My guess is that `recipe_id` column is `int` datatype, but in your update SQL you have `WHERE recipe_id = '" . $id . "'`. Those single quotes (`'`) around `$id` will cast it as a string. Should be: `WHERE recipe_id = " . (int) $id . "`

Comment: By the way, I strongly recommend you look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for your SQL.

Comment: Hi Dominic, thanks for your quick reply, I've tried changing it to " . (int) $id . " but unfortunately still didn't work. Will definitely checkout prepared statements! Thanks for the tip.